# UTF8 Russian or Asian strings, help with encoding in PHP

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

I am having trouble properly encoding UTF8 strings. I am fetching data from meta title/description data of remote international website and then I use javascript to place the string into a input text box.

Some sites encode properly, however some do not and return odd characters. For example two sites I am having trouble are:
    `http://www.telki.ru/` (careful: adult content) and `http://www.backchina.com/`

I have tried utf8_encode,decode etc, but cannot figure out a universal solution that will work with all sites. Help please!

Answer (score 4):

Parse the HTTP response headers and the META tags for the appropriate charset to use.

Comment: Is this the only solution? Can you help me out with an approach?

Comment: Well... you *could* try picking an encoding at random and using it... but I think you'll find my way a bit more effective.

Comment: Can you help me out with how to do it your way?